# How would you diagnose an integrated network card that doesn't show up on the device list?

Tags: networking, diagnostic

I've been setting up a server based around a Gigabyte GA-G33M-DS2R motherboard (G33, PCH9R with integrated Realtek 811B network device. I've enabled it in the BIOS, but it doesn't show up in the pre-boot PCI device list, isn't recognized by Windows (even after installing the chipset and networking drivers) and doesn't even show up via `lspci`.

I've tried cycling power, disabling, cycling again, enabling, cycling again etc. to no avail. I'm sort of at a loss at this point; the board isn't under warranty anymore, but I'd rather not have to replace it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried erasing the CMOS settings (using the battery clear jumper)?  Also try flashing the BIOS.

If neither of those makes it show up in lspci, then your integrated network is toast.  Doesn't necessarily mean you have to ditch the motherboard, but you'll have to get an expansion card for network access.

Comment: No, I haven't - I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Ugh, ended up being a dead integrated NIC. Had to buy a separate PCI controller to sort it out.